# Using Python need to search a string

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, list

Using Python I want to search a string, Input array list contains both integer and string, Also search string also has number. Below are my example. How to get that output.?

```
sr = pd.Series(['New_York12', 'Isbon212', 'Tokyo31', 'Paris031', 'Munich012']) 
result = sr.str.contains('is|12.0', regex=True,case=False) 

Expected Output:
True
True
False
True
True
```

Comment: Did you try to print `result`?

Comment: `print("Expected Output:")`
`for row in result:`
    `print(row)`

Comment: Sorry. A small change```'is|12.0'```. I want in this case.

Comment: a pandas Series is really needed for this?!

Comment: When I convert my pandas dataframe to string ```Model_Str='|'.join(map(str, (Model_data[model].head(Model_data[model].count()))))``` integer data converted to string and with .0 Ex **is|12.0**. In this case it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to output the results is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd


sr = pd.Series(['New_York12', 'Isbon212', 'Tokyo31', 'Paris031', 'Munich012']) 
results = sr.str.contains('is|12.0|12', regex=True,case=False)

for result in results:
    print (result)
```

This returns

```
True
True
False
True
True
```

Comment: Sorry. A small change'is|12.0'. I want in this case.

Comment: Can you pls Run I check. I'm getting below output:
```City 1    False
City 2     True
City 3    False
City 4     True
City 5    False```

Comment: i get the same as you - what is the output you want?

Comment: I mentioned in Question. **Expected output**

```Expected Output:
True
True
False
True
True ```

Comment: i have updated it again - this create the output you want. I think this answers the original question of how to print the output. If you want help with the filter this sounds like a different question.

Comment: Input should be **12.0**

Comment: When I convert my pandas dataframe to string Model_Str='|'.join(map(str, (Model_data[model].head(Model_data[model].count())))) integer data converted to string and with .0 Ex is|12.0. In this case it's not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208965/discussion-between-codecupboard-and-aravinthkumar-j).